# Laravel 8 - unsupported_grant_type

Tags: php, laravel, http, http-post, laravel-8

Tengo un problema con lo siguiente:

- Estoy creando una API (soy nuevo en esto)
- Con esta misma API quiero consumir otra API o WebService
- En Postman hago una petición get a la URL y me devuelve OK el access_token, pero en el proyecto de Laravel me devuelve: `"error" => "unsupported_grant_type".`

Dejo mi código:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

$response = Http::withHeaders([
            'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        ])->post('http://url:52904/Token', [
            'userName' => 'menganito',
            'password' => 'pepito',
            'grant_type' => 'password'
        ]);

        dd($response->json());
```

Probé instalando **Laravel Passport**, pero no estoy usando por ahora una BD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi problema fue el x-www-form-urlencoded

lo solucione asi:

```
$response = Http::asForm()->post('http://url.com', [
                'userName' => 'user',
                'password' => 'pass',
                'grant_type' => 'password'
        ]);

dd($response->json());
```

Comment: Gracia por compartir la repuesta @naqzher

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esta pequeña sugerencia.

```
$response = Http::withHeaders(['content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'])->post('http://url:52904/Token', [
  'userName' => 'menganito',
  'password' => 'pepito',
  'grant_type' => 'password'
]);
return response()->json($response);
```

Comment: lo intente, tal vez sea por el x-www-form-urlencoded, xq cuando envio en postman la opcion de form-data me devuelve el mismo texto: "error" => "unsupported_grant_type"